# I get null when I pass JSON array with JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I am facing a problem with the JQuery ajax function.

I am trying to send a simple json through the ajax asshown below.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'NewFile.jsp', 
            type: 'GET',
            data: {"datasource":"hello1", definition:[{val1:"hello3"}]},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("Successfully posted "+JSON.stringify(json));
            }
        });
```

The problem is that when I do

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("datasource")); 
System.out.println(request.getParameter("definition"));
```

in my `NewFile.jsp` then I get hello1 for the first and null for the second.

Why I get null value in the second `println()`?

Thanks

Comment: `request.getParameter("definition[0][val1]")` might contain the expected value.

Comment: @SalmanA What you said worked like a charm. Thanks. Is it possible to get the definition array as a java collection because I need to loop through this array? Or is it possible to take the all the json in the data field as a string in my jsp page in order to work with gson?

Comment: do u using any framework such as struts?

Comment: No I don't ... :( @gjman2

Comment: Seems like JSP does not parse query string variables such as `a[0]=foo&a[1]=bar` like the way PHP does. You could convert your array to a comma separated list or "POST" the data in JSON format and decode it on server side.

Answer (score 0):

In the `url` variable inside your ajax object, give the full URL of your request. Like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'www.google.com/', 
            type: 'GET',
            data: {"datasource":"hello1", definition:[{val1:"hello3"}]},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("Successfully posted "+JSON.stringify(json));
            }
        });
```

Also, always make sure that there is a `failure` variable inside your object literal, so that you know it happened, but failed. Helps with debugging.